# ROR route with parentheses in constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to create a rails route for movies (on the root path) that has parentheses containing the movie's year in it.

E.g. Men in black => "/men-in-black-(1997)"

My route is:

```
resources :movies,
  path:'/',
  only:[ :index, :list, :show ],
  constraints: { id: /[A-Za-z0-9-]+\(\d{4}\)/ }
```

When I use this route (movie_path(Movie.first)), I get

```
"ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches: ..."
```

When I change the route constraint to:

```
constraints: { id: /[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\\(\d{4}\\\)/ }
```

the route works when using the url routing helper. However, the route doesn't work for the reverse mapping (e.g. taking "/men-in-black-(1997)" and routing it to the correct action/controller). When I run (from console):

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("/men-in-black-(1997)")
```

I get the same routing error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches
```

The problem seems to be associated to how rails escapes regex's in routing. For escaping with \( the object-to-route map fails, but url-to-route works. But when escaping with \\\( it is the opposite.

Anyone have any tips or experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround hack you could try:

```
constraints: { id: /[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\(\d{4}\\\)|\(\d{4}\))/ }
```

That is, make the constraint accept either, if it accepts one in one case and the other in the other case.

Which is to say: that's weird, I have no idea why Rails would do that or how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't have a lot of experience writing regex constraints, but you could always do a wildcard route and then sanitize in the controller.

```
match 'movies/*movie' => 'movie#action'
```

This will give you access to a :movie param with all the characters input

Comment: Unfortunately I'm required to route movies from the root path for seo purposes.